# How do I use MariaDB instead of MySQL?

Tags: database

I need to use MariaDB instead of MySQL in Drupal 8. I have already installed MariaDB in my local system.

How do I use it with Drupal 8? What changes are required to use it?

Comment: Look this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMqLsbpSTrA

Answer (score 4):

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL. No changes are required.

You'll obviously need to update your connection/credential details to match the new server, but as far as configuring Drupal to use MariaDB, there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8 requires  MySQL 5.5.3/MariaDB 5.5.20/Percona Server 5.5.8 or higher with InnoDB as the primary storage engine. If you have the right version of MariaDB, Drupal will work without you doing anything different from when using MySQL, which also means you don't need to select a different driver, or tell Drupal the database engine is not MySQL.
Be sure you are using the correct credentials for accessing the database.

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement, which means PHP will think to be talking with MySQL, so you don't need to do anything different from when you would use MySQL.

#### References

- [System requirements / Database server](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/database-server)
- [PDO and MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195013/pdo-and-mariadb)